# Microsoft Access "if" statement

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

A very specific question - wondering if someone would simply be able to put together the code for me! I have no experience with code... at all.

I have a table consisting completely of associate information (Name, Phone, ID, Position, etc). I'm building a report on which I only want the Name to display, but ONLY IF their Position = "Tech"

I've come to find this formula for displaying their names in the "last name, first name" format:

=[LastName] & ", " & [FirstName]

but as I said... I only want this script to run if they're a "Tech"   how would I write out the "IF" statement to make this work?

Comment: seriously - you have included a tag whose description says "do not use  this tag"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may notice that your question has attracted a couple of downvotes. That's because many SO members can be very sensitive to questions asking someone else to write code for you, so "wondering if someone would simply be able to put together the code for me!" is probably not the best way to phase your questions. (That type of question is sometimes referred to a "Gimme teh codez!")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place for that would be in the query - add "WHERE Position = 'Tech'".  Assuming you only want Techs to show up on the report.

If you want everyone to show up but only want names to be visible for techs, you can use an IIf statement:  = IIf(Position = "Tech", [LastName] & ", " & [FirstName], "")

That will show the name for a tech, or a blank for anyone else.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Only issue is at the end of that statement... the "IF NOT" portion of it, you could say. If the position is not "Tech" by this statement, it leaves a blank box. I just wanted it to skip the  "non-Tech's."

Comment: In that case you probably just want to edit the query for the report, and do the filtering in the WHERE clause.  That way, you don't have to worry about non-Techs being there in the first place.